# Trying to exclude a subset within a few days of a report

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to exclude trades of a certain typology if they are less than 4 days but this filter im using is super slow in returning results. it also doesnt capture trades which are booked 10th of may expiring 13th june which it should. if I amend it to include these it will also include trades within the same month less than 4 days. can someone help me make it more efficient and capturing what I want. using orcale sql developer

```
    and ( DC.M_TYPOLOGY <> 'Repo BD' OR (DC.M_TYPOLOGY ='Repo BD' and 
(((to_char( DC.M_OPTMAT , 'YYYY')- to_char (DC.M_TRADEDATE, 'YYYY'))= 0 
and (to_char( DC.M_OPTMAT , 'MM')- to_char (DC.M_TRADEDATE, 'MM') < 1))
 and (to_char( DC.M_OPTMAT , 'DD')- to_char (DC.M_TRADEDATE, 'DD') > 4))))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  THis question is way too broad and lacking detail.  What does "super slow" mean?  How much data?  Please show sample data and full query,and expected output.  Have you run an explain plan on the query?

Comment: " 10th of may expiring 13th june " is a lot longer than four days. You need more clarity regarding your business rules.

Answer (score 0):

All that conversion is unnecessary (and wrong - what happens when trades span year end?). We can do arithmetic with Oracle dates so this is the same:

```
( DC.M_TYPOLOGY <> 'Repo BD' 
   OR (DC.M_TYPOLOGY ='Repo BD' 
   and DC.M_TRADEDATE - DC.M_OPTMAT < 4 )
)
```

*Note: this answer posted before the recent edit to the question. I'm leaving this in place but I will revise it once the OP has clarified the rules they want to enforce.*

Of course, this may not speed your query up. Performance problems can arise from many different causes and there simply isn't enough detail provided.